# Azure OpenAI Embeddings vs OpenAI Embeddings

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-openai, text-embedding-ada-002

Is anyone getting different results from Azure OpenAI embeddings deployment using text-embedding-ada-002 than the ones from OpenAI? Same text, same model, and the results are considerably far in the vector space.

What's recommended for embeddings?

Comment: Hey any new updates on this one? I am not able to find a way to create a deployment with model-version 2 but their docuemnts don't seem to have any details on that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/azureopenaistable/deployments/update?tabs=HTTP#definitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current AOAI's text-embedding-ada-002 is somewhat different from OAI's. Our model currently supports only 2K tokens, while OAI can support 8K tokens.

Azure OpenAI doesn’t allow batched embeddings. You need to use multiple simultaneous requests. If you hit the maximum req/min, you will need to ask Azure a quota increase.